# DataTable to Excel without special library?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, export, export-to-excel

Is there any easy way to create a `Excel` file from a DataTable without using special libraries like [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/)?

I have tried the following code :

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pathAndFilename, false))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < datatable.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        colum = datatable.Columns[i];
        sw.Write(colum);

        if (i < datatable.Columns.Count - 1)
            sw.Write(",");
    }
    sw.Write(sw.NewLine);

    foreach (DataRow dr in datatable.Rows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < datatable.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            colum = datatable.Columns[i];

            if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[i]))
                sw.Write(dr[i]);

            if (i < datatable.Columns.Count - 1)
                sw.Write(",");
        }
        sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
    }
}
```

This code will however write all of the content of one row to the first cell of each row.

Comment: That looks like it'll try to write a csv file. Not an excel format file. You'll get no formatting in your document, only the data. If that's ok and your table doesn't contain any string data the code you have should work fine with a `.csv` extension

Comment: If a cell contains a comma, you may write out this cell enclosed in double quotes: `"one,two"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not generating an **Excel** file, it is generating a **CSV** file.
When you say it write all of the content on one row it may be because of regional settings using (`,` instead of `;`) as separators.

Now back to your question, to generate an Excel file you have several options:

1. Using an external library (which is not what you want)
2. Using Excel interop libraries (installed with Excel, or available a small [redistributable package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508))